# Notepad++ Python script can't open file with special characters in filename

Tags: python, utf-8, notepad++

I need to change encoding of some files to UTF-8 via Notepad++. I found this script for Python Script plugin which changes encoding of all files in the folder:

```
import os;
import sys;
filePathSrc="C:\\Users\\" # Path to the folder with files to convert
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filePathSrc):
    for fn in files: 
        if fn[-4:] == '.txt': # Specify type of the files
            notepad.open(root + "\\" + fn)      
            notepad.runMenuCommand("Encoding", "Convert to UTF-8")
            notepad.save()
            notepad.close()
```

It works good for me, except cases when files in the foler have unusual non-english character in the filename (like é, Ø, ß etc). When it comes to this files Notepad++ shows proposal to create new file "C:\Somefile.txt doesn't exist. Create it?" instead of open it.

Plese help to teach Notepad++ and this script open this files too.

Comment: I found advice on Notepad++ [forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/npppythonscript/discussion/1188886/thread/8f556f46/) to set encoding of file path itself to UTF-8, but I'm not familiar with programming and don't know how to modify this particular script like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue appears because of space between words. Notepad++ has a problem like that. There is a solution here if it works http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/bdf6db82